# Is it possible to generate .sln file from .ninja file?

Tags: visual-studio, chromium, ninja, sln-file

I was messing around with chromium and was left with a build.ninja file. I want to see if it's possible to generate in some way a .sln file so I could build the project in visual studio to use build acceleration programs on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command to generate a Visual Studio solution:

```
gn gen out\YourBuildFolder --ide=vs
```

You should execute the above command from the `src` folder. After that command completes, you should see `all.sln` in the `YourBuildFolder` folder